Не могу установить 1с-битрикс
Устанавливаю битрикс по этому видео - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hYjUB0vrJo0&list=PL8Kt1m2oRch5M1bA334BRwFybdDe38Byd&index=4.
На 6 пункте выдает ошибвку - "The requested URL /bitrix/urlrewrite.php was not found on this server. Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request."
По этому пути у меня нет этого файла. Скиньте этот файл, кто может, пожалуйста.

Проверьте права на папки, скорее всего, сайту не хватает прав на создание папок и файлов в каталоке, определённом под сайт.

<?
include_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . 
'/bitrix/modules/main/include/urlrewrite.php');
if (file_exists($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/404.php'))
    include_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/404.php');
?>

